# The media uploader is not working properly?

Tags: magento-1.8, module, media

> <sup>**This question already has an answer here:**</sup>
>   
> [Magento - Upload HTTP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994648/magento-upload-http-error)

I am following this [thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/11667/P30/) for setting the media uploader for uploading multiple images like image upload in product images.

I got the media tab in the form but when I click on `upload files` I am getting an error  "upload http error". I dont know where I was going wrong in this thread.

[image]
How can I resolve this. I have no idea why this is happening.

If there is something wrong then how can media uploader can be used in the custom module. What are the proper step of using it. I didn't find anything on media uploader on the net.

How can I make this right.

Comment: Are you trying to upload the images to a htaccess protected site?

Comment: No my site is not htaccess protected site.

Comment: media uploader is working fine in product section. but not here. I am using custom module

Comment: What is in `var/log/system.log` file?

Comment: This post is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994648/magento-upload-http-error

Comment: Question was asked at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994648/magento-upload-http-error

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi there is nothing in my `system.log` file

Comment: It can be also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233627/swfupload-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Check the response from the controller, you can just hook into the HTTP traffic with e.g. wireshark, fiddler or HTTPscoop.

In the response you find the error.

Comment: I am not getting any response from the controller, and I have no idea how this media uploader works. I am searching on the net for hours about this, but I didn't get the working flow of this.

Comment: The uploader is written in flex, what is (I think) a framework for flash. Whatever, it is his own little universe, which means, the requests are not handled through your browser, so you need a httpsniffer to get it. Capture what the controller responses and you have your problem.